# Impact of changing @SequenceGenerator allocationSizeParam

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Currently i don't have allocation size set in my @SequenceGenerator annotation. So the default value is 50

```
int allocationSize() default 50;
```

As expected there is gap in ids of the correspoding table.

Now i want to change the allocationSize to 1. Is there any chance of id collision then?

Comment: i want to know how it actually handles uniqueness and know the theory well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experiments to exactly know what will be happening if suddenly someone change the allocationSize from default one.

Short answer to my question is - **Yes there will be duplicacy in Id generation.**

---

Before changing **allocation** size in my application **allocationSize = 50 (default)**

when sequence value is 4 in db, hibernate start generating id from 4*5 = 200

```
DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 200, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
```

Which is expected behavior of **Hilo generator** with this **default allocationSize**

---

Then when i change my **allocationSize = 1** and deploy my application again.

Now,

**Hilo generator** start id generation from `currentSequenceVal * allocationSize` as it did before, for **currentSequenceValue  = 5**, it will generate id 6, 7, 8 ....

which will eventually lead it to duplicate id generation.

---

Now the solution is to drop the sequence and create the sequence again with starting value currently used maximum id.